# pass $scope variable to templateUrl angularjs without displaying in url

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass some data from controller to templateUrl. Is it possible? I don't want to show data in browser's url.

Assume controller is like this:

```js
    app.controller('PageController', function ($scope) {
     $scope.index_init = function(role){
      role.config = JSON.parse(role.config);
      $scope.brand_id = role.config.brand_id;
     }
    });
```

And url is like this:

```js
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/coupons", {
  templateUrl: function(){
            // i want brand_id here
   if(brand_id)
    return "/list?brand_id=" + brand_id;
   else
    return "/list";
  }, 
  controller: "ListController"})
.otherwise("/404", {template: "error", controller: "ErrorController"});
```

How can I get brand_id in templateUrl? I don't want to pass brand_id in url like "/coupons?brand_id=2" or like "/coupons/2".

**NOTE:** Controller is running before clicking on url link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know (from internet) using normal java script inside angular is not good practice. I don't know why. If it is wrong please tell me also.

Here is what I did:
I defied a variable before 
    `app.config()`

```
var brand_id = null;
```

and then assign value to this variable in controller. Now it is available in templateUrl.
Of course user can change/ access this variable using console but it will not be risky for me because I just want to remove this extra parameter from url because it was looking dirty.

Comment: just a couple quick things; this probably works to keep the url from looking "dirty", but this also keeps your users from being able to bookmark their state in the app.  This might be ok, but it totally depends on the use situation.  As to using "normal java script", I think you misunderstand;  Angular is JavaScript, so there is nothing wrong with JavaScript;  it **is** discouraged to use JQuery to do DOM manipulation with angular, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @Claies I have no problem with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass data via a url you can not hide it.

To have consistant data throught the app you could consider using $rootScope but remember global variables are only to be used when necessary.

Comment: I have added $rootScope to both controller and templateUrl function. Then I assign $rootScope.brand_id in controller. But in templateUrl I am still getting undefined. using console.log, I can see that my controller is running before the templateUrl.

Comment: The way routing and controllers work means that when you hit a new route that is in your state provider your controller is run. Make sure your logic takes this into account

Comment: Thanks for response, I will also try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide that but you could try an hack to this could be using ui-routers nested views instead of ng-route, So when brand_id exists, it would load a different view, and in that template there would be a logic to check the data.

[Angular Ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

Comment: @babahide Thanks for response, it seems a tricky method. At this moment, I am in hurry and I will learn it on some other day :) I am editing this comment because I had taged joy here also instead of you